# Check LibreOffice presentation for picture license

Tags: libreoffice

I have a presentation that I would like to publish. I am pretty sure most of the images are CC-By-SA, but I would like to make sure.

Is there a tool that:

- exports all images in an .odp-file
- searches for these on Google Images
- finds the license+attribution for these images or at least finds the URL where the images are

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the images by unzipping the .odp file and looking in the resulting Pictures subdirectory.  However it looks like the filename is not the original name, so I do not know how you could use this for searching.

If you are interested in writing macros, have a look at http://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=64969.  Again I do not think you can determine the original filename this way.  If your presentation contains captions that tell the name of each image then it may be possible to search based on those names.